# Why setState() is calling reloading listview upon item selected, how to stop it ? in flutter App

Tags: flutter

My app reads data from PostgreSQL and displays on the screen in a listview. While selecting an item from listview **app is getting refreshed and items are appending to existing list**. My intention is to read data only once from the DB, display in list view, select single/multiple and proceed with processing. Any suggestions would be appriciated.

```
import 'package:e2/Models/MasterPositions.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:e2/Models/model_positions.dart';

class MasterControl extends StatefulWidget {
  const MasterControl({super.key});

  @override
  State<MasterControl> createState() => _MasterControlState();
}

class _MasterControlState extends State<MasterControl> {
  List<MasterPositions> selectedContacts = [];
  List<MasterPositions> fetchedPositions = [];
  List<MasterPositions> positions = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Master Control"),
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
              future: ModelsPositions().fetchPositionsData(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                List<dynamic> positionsRaw = snapshot.data ?? [];
                for (var pos in positionsRaw) {
                  positions.add(MasterPositions(
                    custID: pos[0],
                    custName: pos[1],
                    mtm: double.tryParse(pos[2]) ?? 0.0,
                    availableCash: double.tryParse(pos[3]) ?? 0.0,
                  ));
                }
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  default:
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return const Center(
                          child: Text(
                              'Error while loading Master Positions screen'));
                    } else {
                      return buildPositions(positions);
                    }
                }
              },
            )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildPositions(List<dynamic> positions) {
    return ListView.builder(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: positions.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final pos = positions[index];
          final custID = pos.custID;
          final custName = pos.custName;
          final mtm = pos.mtm;
          final availableCash = pos.availableCash;
          final isSelected = pos.isSelected;

          return ListTile(
            horizontalTitleGap: -5,
            title: Card(
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: [
                        Text(custID),
                        const SizedBox(height: 5),
                        Text(custName)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    fit: FlexFit.tight,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: [
                        Text('MTM       : $mtm',
                            softWrap: false,
                            style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto')),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Text(
                          'Available : $availableCash',
                          softWrap: false,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            leading: isSelected
                ? Icon(
                    Icons.check_circle,
                    color: Colors.green[700],
                  )
                : const Icon(
                    Icons.check_circle_outline,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                positions[index].isSelected = !positions[index].isSelected;
                if (positions[index].isSelected == true) {
                  selectedContacts.add(MasterPositions(
                      custID: custID,
                      custName: custName,
                      mtm: mtm,
                      availableCash: availableCash));
                } else if (positions[index].isSelected == false) {
                  selectedContacts.removeWhere(
                      (element) => element.custID == positions[index].custID);
                }
              });
            },
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: It'll help if you share part of your code that deals with this logic you're stating here.

Answer (score 0):

I often use something like this:

```dart
           if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      if (snapshot.data!.isNotEmpty) {
                List<dynamic> positionsRaw = snapshot.data ?? [];
                 for (var pos in positionsRaw) {
                  positions.add(MasterPositions(
                    custID: pos[0],
                    custName: pos[1],
                    mtm: double.tryParse(pos[2]) ?? 0.0,
                    availableCash: double.tryParse(pos[3]) ?? 0.0,
                  ));
                      
                      return buildPositions(positions);
                      } else {
                      //  return something
                      }
                    } else {
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
```

And so you can guarantee that your widget will be built with data, and only be rebuilt when your new data it's loaded